# multirow, multicolumn problems

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

[image]

Hello, Could somebody help me on how to produce this table in latex. I have tried, but the subheadings float away anytime I tried. I would be glad to have it as soon as possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the code you've tried to come up. This would help clarify what you mean by subheadings floating away. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Since parts of tables do not float away from other parts by default, it will be difficult to give much help otherwise except to say that something in your code is surely wrong.

Comment: Nothing in that table requires **multirow**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use booktabs package and create your table easily as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
Accident & Ultimate & Reserve & RMSEP & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CoV} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Source of Error}\\
year & & & &Ultimate & Reserve& Parameter & Process\\
\midrule
2005 &11,148 &0&&&&&\\
2006 &10,663&15&0&0.00\%&2\%&49\%&51\% \\
2007&10,662&26&1&0.01\%&3\%&34\%&66\%\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: neattbl]